# Trivial Fundamental Group Notation (1 or 0)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I read in some books that have the notation $\pi_1(X)=0$ to mean $X$ has trivial fundamental group.

My question is why 0 and not 1, i.e. $\pi_1(X)=1$?

Is this a case of additive notation versus multiplicative notation?

Thanks!

Comment: No matter how you write it, there is only one group (up to isomorphism) with one element.

Comment: All of the higher fundamental groups are abelian, so additive notation is generally preferred for them. Even though the same can't be said in general for the first fundamental group, it's easy just to treat it as the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see this as an additive/multiplicative notation issue, exactly as you say. It's like when one talks about exact sequences of abelian groups or modules, one often writes
$$
0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0
$$
whereas one may more likely write
$$
1 \to X \to Y \to Z \to 1
$$
for an exact sequence in the category of all groups.

Comment: Bastard, I was about to write this! :)

Comment: I've even seen an exact sequence with $1$ at the left end and $0$ at the right end, because the left group was typically thought of multiplicatively and the right one additively.

Comment: $0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^* \to 1$ is one example.